# WPA2 / wpa_supplicant wireless hotspot logs

Tags: linux, ubuntu, wireless-networking, wireless-access-point, wifi-configuration

Using Ubuntu 16.04, I use a wireless wi-fi adapter to host a wi-fi hotspot. Lately someone's been trying guess my (42 character) wi-fi password. When they fail to authenticate to my hotspot, I receive the below messages in my syslog:

```
Jan 01 12:39:20 Hostname wpa_supplicant[1370]: WPA: wpa_sm_step() called recursively
Jan 01 12:39:32 Hostname wpa_supplicant[1370]: WPA: wpa_sm_step() called recursively
Jan 01 12:39:45 Hostname wpa_supplicant[1370]: WPA: wpa_sm_step() called recursively
```

Would it be possible to increase the verbosity of these error messages and view what kinds of passwords they're trying?

Comment: That log message doesn’t suggest a bad password attempt to me. What makes you think someone is trying to guess your password?

Comment: I can reproduce the message by attempting to authenticate with an incorrect password

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you won’t be able to see what passwords were being attempted. WPA2, like WPA before it, authenticates the AP to the client at the same time, and via the same mechanism, as it authenticates the client to the AP, and they do it in a way that lets them both know if the other knows the same password, without either revealing its password to the other.

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate your response. Where can I learn more about "without either revealing its password to the other."